# How to cover code related to Custom Metadata logic?

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, test-setup, custom-metadata, test-automation

I have a custom metadata called ***Custom_Metadata__mdt***.

I have one custom boolean field in that custom metadata called ***Custom_Boolean_Field__c***.

I need to execute some logic only if value of ***Custom_Boolean_Field__c*** on custom metadata record with name *'default'* is true.

I have a big class with much logic like this

```
public class Services{
    public static void methodToCallFromTrigger() {
        Custom_Metadata__mdt meta = [ SELECT Custom_Boolean_Field__c FROM Custom_Metadata__mdt WHERE MasterLabel = 'default'];
        if ( meta.Custom_Boolean_Field__c ) {
             // many many lines
        }
    }

}
```

If I uncheck ***Custom_Boolean_Field__c*** checkbox on ***Custom_Metadata__mdt*** *default* record then my coverage will drop to almost zero.

Is there a way to get 100% coverage even when value on ***Custom_Boolean_Field__c*** is false on ***Custom_Metadata__mdt*** *default* record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rewrite your code in a following way

```
public class Services{
    public static Custom_Metadata__mdt defaultMeta { 
        get {
            if ( defaultMeta == null )
                defaultMeta = [ SELECT Custom_Boolean_Field__c FROM Custom_Metadata__mdt WHERE MasterLabel = 'default']; 
            return defaultMeta;
        } set; }

    public static void methodToCallFromTrigger() {
        if ( defaultMeta.Custom_Boolean_Field__c ) {
             // many many lines
        }
    }
}
```

}

then in your test before using metadata, you should run this code

```
Services.defaultMeta = (Custom_Metadata__mdt) JSON.deserialize( '{"Custom_Boolean_Field__c":true}', Custom_Metadata__mdt.class )
```